Is GCC correct in rejecting overload between ref-qualified and non-ref-qualified member function?
If I understand this correctly, [over.load] doesn't exist in c++23, and so what I read in [over.load]/2.3 should not be true anymore, so this code
struct Foo {
  int const& bar() const;
  int bar() &&;
  int& bar() &;
};

should be valid c++23, even though it was invalid c++20.
Clang reflects this understanding of mine, but GCC doesn't, as it fails to compile with -std=c++23 too.
Is this a bug in GCC? I don't find it here (some refer to -std=c++20, others are just not the same thing).

It was moved into [basic.scope.scope], I believe: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.scope.scope#4 The wording is a tad odd for me, so I'm not actually sure if your example is valid or not. For what it's worth, MSVC also rejects your code with /std:c++latest

This was part of the large name lookup cleanup paper that was P1787.
Basically the original rule was in [over.load]/2:

Member function declarations with the same name and the same parameter-type-list as well as member function template declarations with the same name, the same parameter-type-list, and the same template parameter lists cannot be overloaded if any of them, but not all, have a ref-qualifier ([dcl.fct]). [ Example:
class Y {
  void h() &;
  void h() const &;             // OK
  void h() &&;                  // OK, all declarations have a ref-qualifier
  void i() &;
  void i() const;               // ill-formed, prior declaration of i
                                // has a ref-qualifier
};

— end example ]

And the new rule is based in terms of pairwise declaration correspondence, the relevant part here being in [basic.scope.scope]/3:

Two non-static member functions have corresponding object parameters if:

exactly one is an implicit object member function with no ref-qualifier and the types of their object parameters ([dcl.fct]), after removing top-level references, are the same, or
their object parameters have the same type.


Just looking at the Y::i example earlier, before the rule was "any but not all have a ref-qualifier means ill-formed" and now the rule (which had to be refined with the introduction of deducing this) is simply based on whether the object parameters are the same type.
So the Y::i example becomes well-formed because the two objects parameters have types Y& and Y const&, which differ. Likewise the Foo example in OP becomes well-formed.
There wasn't really a reason to reject before, and the new formulation makes it possible to compare implicit and explicit object member functions.
In any case, it's trivial to ensure the example compiles, so might as well do it:
  struct Foo {
-   int const& bar() const;
+   int const& bar() const&;
    int bar() &&;
    int& bar() &;
  };

